# Change order on object navigator

Tags: oracle, object, report, navigator

I just need to change the frame order in the paper layout´s body, on the object navigator.
For example, i have frame M_1, m_2, m_44, m_3. I want to move down the m_44 to the be the last frame on body.
Is there any shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you want to do; is it just about *sorting* frames by their names? If so, that's in vain. Any time you add another frame, it'll get a unique name, and - depending on where it is located (on the layout) - it might be placed anywhere in the Object Navigator.

A simple option is to rename frames:

- rename M_3 to M_5
- rename M_44 to M_3
- rename M_5 to M_4

Now you'll have them placed in desired order.

---

However, if it is about relocating them in the layout, then **move** them forward (or backward) until they are on correct locations. Pay attention, though, as you might end up in different kinds of errors.

---

Oh, yes - to answer your question: no, I don't think that there's any shortcut for this.

Comment: hi!
Yes... I need to relocate the items.. a entire block of frames.

Comment: well... 
My problem is that I have a frame that should be showed on the end of my report.. But when its printed, the frame goes to the middle of it, right in the center of another block.
I thought if i just relocate maybe it works... but, do you have another idea?

Comment: You'll have to fix it within the layout editor. I don't know of any other option. How to do it? Pay attention to space between frames. Reports Builder tends to spoil things if there's no enough space. Also, maybe **anchor** might help (by anchoring one frame to another).